# Join network namespace from inside user namespace

Tags: linux, linux-namespaces

Root creates a network namespace `testns`, and clone with [`CLONE_NEWUSER`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/user_namespaces.7.html) flag to get the child inside an user namespace. Then the child tries to join `testns` by calling [`setns`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setns.2.html), which shows the permission denied. **Is there any alternative to let the child inside an user namespace to join a network namespace?**

Just wrote up this following test: (Before running, I created `testns` by calling `sudo ip netns add testns`)

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define STACK_SIZE (1024 * 1024)
static char child_stack[STACK_SIZE];

static void update_map(char *mapping, char *map_file) {
    int fd, j;
    size_t map_len;

    map_len = strlen(mapping);
    for (j = 0; j < map_len; j++)
        if (mapping[j] == ',')
            mapping[j] = '\n';

    fd = open(map_file, O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "open %s: %s\n", map_file, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (write(fd, mapping, map_len) != map_len) {
        fprintf(stderr, "write %s: %s\n", map_file, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    close(fd);
}

static void proc_setgroups_write(pid_t child_pid, char *str) {
    char setgroups_path[PATH_MAX];
    int fd;

    snprintf(setgroups_path, PATH_MAX, "/proc/%ld/setgroups",
            (long) child_pid);

    fd = open(setgroups_path, O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        if (errno != ENOENT)
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: open %s: %s\n", setgroups_path,
                strerror(errno));
        return;
    }

    if (write(fd, str, strlen(str)) == -1)
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: write %s: %s\n", setgroups_path,
            strerror(errno));

    close(fd);
}

static void update_userns(pid_t pid, char *uidMap, char *gidMap) {
    char map_path[PATH_MAX];

    snprintf(map_path, PATH_MAX, "/proc/%ld/uid_map", (long) pid);
    update_map(uidMap, map_path);

    proc_setgroups_write(pid, "deny");
    snprintf(map_path, PATH_MAX, "/proc/%ld/gid_map", (long) pid);
    update_map(gidMap, map_path);
}

static int join_netns(char *netns_name) {
    char netns_path[256];
    snprintf(netns_path, sizeof(netns_path), "/var/run/netns/%s", netns_name);
    int fd = open(netns_path, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "open netns path failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (setns(fd, CLONE_NEWNET) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "set netns failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}

static int child(void* arg) {
    // Sleep so that userns has the correct mapping.
    sleep(1);

    return join_netns("testns");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    uid_t uid = getuid();
    char mapping[10];
    snprintf(mapping, 10, "0 %d 1", uid);

    int pid1 = clone(child, child_stack + STACK_SIZE, CLONE_NEWUSER | SIGCHLD, NULL);
    if (pid1 == -1) {
        perror("Clone");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    update_userns(pid1, mapping, mapping);

    if (waitpid(pid1, NULL, 0) == -1) {
        perror("waitpid"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The kernel will do a security check that the userns "owner"/creator of the network namespace matches before allowing a join to an existing network namespace.

You can definitely join a network namespace once inside a user namespace, but that initial network namespace must be created with the same user namespace. In container runtimes like the `runc` tool, you can validate this by starting a simple container in a user namespace with a network namespace created, and then start a second container with references to the first container's *user* and *network* namespace paths. I demo'd this using `runc` at a previous DockerCon; you can see me sharing the user namespace and network namespace [in this segment starting at 41:24](https://youtu.be/ZAhzoz2zJj8?t=41m24s)